# Добавление MX записи

Tags: dns

Какую MX запись мне нужно добавить для домена, чтобы работала входящая почта на сервере? На данный момент exim4 пишет: 550 Unrouteable address. Думаю из-за отсутствия MX записей.

Comment: Какую запись добавить - зависит от. Например, у вас домен example.com. Вы придумали имя mx.example.com. Указываете для домена example.com запись типа MX, указывающую на mx.example.com. И до кучи прописываете для mx.example.com ip-адрес, где реально находится этот самый почтовый сервер. Примерно так.

Comment: Выходит нужно сделать так: прописываем example.com MX mx.example.com и mx.example.com TXT IP ?

Comment: Нет. Тип TXT тут не причем. Необходимо два типа записей: MX, с указанием целого числа (приоритет почтового сервера) и его имя, и тип A, для указания ip почтового сервера. Если у вас управление DNS-ом через некую панель, в которой нет типа MX, то как вариант можно обойтись только типом A для самого домена example.com. Почтовые сервера используют для доставки почты и этот тип, при отсутствии записи MX.

Comment: Можете написать, что конкретно нужно прописать в DNS домена?

Comment: И какой приоритет нужно писать?

Comment: Добавил в ответ, для наглядности. Но у меня есть подозрение, что у вас это не из-за MX записей.

Comment: После добавления MX записей пишет: cannot be resolved at this time: lowest numbered MX record points to local host

Comment: А вы с чьего ответа списывали? Мой уже минуснули, а у вас ошибка связана с тем, что MX запись указывает на 127.0.0.1 судя по всему.

Comment: Для пробы взял ответ stxdtm. В MX указывал ip сервера.

Comment: В MX типе нельзя указывать ip адрес, только имя. Если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Там всё верно указал, смысл только. Ошибка осталась.

Comment: Вот я и говорю, что не уверен, что вам надо MX-ы «крутить». Тем более у вас какая-то панелька для этого. Если это хостинг - обратитесь в саппорт, иначе мы тут неопределённое время потратим.

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема всё-таки в конфигах самого exim4.

Comment: Тогда удаляйте этот вопрос, т.к. он "неполезен", и создавайте новый - про конфигурацию exim.

Answer (score 0):

Mx-запись нужна для того, чтобы серверы, отсылающие почту для Вашего домена знали, кто занимается обработкой этой почты. Поэтому, для корректной работы Ваше доменное имя должно иметь MX-запись. Пример:

```
example.com.      IN A 127.0.0.1
                  IN MX 10 mx.example.com

mx.example.com.   IN A 127.0.0.1
```

По порядку:

- первая строка связывает доменное имя example.com с ip-адресом 127.0.0.1 (на ip-адрес не обращайте внимания, лень выдумывать - вместо них должен быть ip-адрес Вашего сервера);
- вторая строка сообщает, что обработкой почты, приходящей для домена example.com, занимается сервер mx.example.com. Число 10 - это приоритет. Чем оно меньше - тем большую важность имеет почтовый сервер (актуально, например, если у Вас их несколько). Можно поставить, 0, 1, 5, 10 (если у вас одна mx-запись, это не очень важно);
- ну и далее описывается, что же такое mx.example.com - эта строка указывает, где находится почтовый сервер. Если он у вас там же, где и основной домен - пишите тот же ip-адрес, что и в первой строчке.

Это минимум, с которого стоит начать, в дальнейшем, возможно, понадобятся дополнительные записи, чтобы некоторые почтовые серверы не считали Вас спамером.

Answer (score -1):

Это, естественно, не ответ, а ради примера.

В нотации DNS-сервера bind (named) это может выглядеть так:

```
    $TTL 1h
    examplecom. IN      SOA     ns.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                    2018060701      ;
                    3600            ;
                    1800            ;
                    604800          ;
                    3600)           ;
                    IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
                    IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
                    IN      MX      5 mx1
                    IN      A       ip.address.example.com

    ns1.example.com.     A       ip.ns1.xx.yy
    ns2.example.com.     A       ip.ns2.xx.yy
    mx1             IN      A       xx.yy.zz.ip
```

Следующие строки описывают почтовый сервер домена:

```
IN      MX      5 mx1
mx1             IN      A       xx.yy.zz.ip
```

Приоритет сервера, в случае только одного почтового сервера для домена, не имеет значения.

В случае двух и более серверов, приоритет указывает на то, в каком порядке почтовый сервер отправителя будет выбирать почтовый сервер домена example.com для доставки почты. **Меньше число - выше приоритет**.